# Do supervisors need to start their own supervisor?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

Let us say I have one supervisor and I need execute some `start_child` for this supervisor. Must I first start all of start my supervisors? Or can I only `supervisor:start_child(my_sup,[])` without my_sup starting?

Comment: I don't think the question is in a answerable form yet ... please elaborate

Comment: You need to start the supervisor first as it the supervisor which then starts the children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you create a supervisor process as part of a supervision tree calling [`supervisor:start_link/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_link-2) or [`supervisor:start_link/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_link-3). The created supervisor process calls `Module:init/1` to find out about restart strategy, maximum restart frequency and child specifications.

This is the example code for a supervisor starting [gen_server](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) (though, you may start other gen_* modules):

```
-module(ch_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).
start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link(ch_sup, []).
init(_Args) ->
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 1, 60},
          [{ch3, {ch3, start_link, []},
            permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [ch3]}]}}.
```

The tuple `{ch3, ...}` is a [child specification](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#spec), which is defined this way:

```
{Id, StartFunc, Restart, Shutdown, Type, Modules}
```

The child specification to start the server `ch3` in the example above looks like:

```
{ch3, {ch3, start_link, []}, permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [ch3]}
```

From the example you see that module `ch3` will be started, monitored and stopped by supervisor, you also see `one_for_one` [**restart strategy**](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id68617) specified which is generally used.  `one_for_one` in the child specification means that if one child process terminates and should be restarted, only that child process is affected, and this is probably your case. Your child processes are started, monitored, restarted and stopped automatically by supervisor.

[`start_child/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2) is used to dynamically add a child specification to the supervisor `SupRef` which starts the corresponding child process.

Thus supervisour is always started first, then its child processes are started automatically or manually based on the **restart strategies**.

Comment: Brutal kill is not always the thing you want. It does not give processes the ability to clean up after themselves in a neat way.

Comment: Yep. Value `int()>=0` is a better way to shutdown the child processes, if the latter need some time to shutdown. There's also `infinity`, used if the child process is another supervisor. OP may want to see [Child Specification](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#spec) section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should first start the supervisor because you will not be starting the child since the supervisor is the one which starts the child. Hope it helps.